# SwiftUI Text: How to always show the last characters of a text even if the text is too long?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-text

I have a text in a frame that can become too long depending on the user input. If a text is too long in SwiftUI, SwiftUI abbreviates it with "..." at the end. Example:

> "That's a very long te..."

But now I want the last x characters to always be displayed, even if the text is too long. A good example of my wish is XCode itself:

[image: Example]

I'd be happy for help.

Comment: Have a look at [truncationMode(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/truncationmode(_:))

Answer (score 1):

### Use [`truncationMode(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/truncationmode(_:))

Example from link above, with `.middle` mode:

```
Text("This is a block of text that will show up in a text element as multiple lines. The text will fill the available space, and then, eventually, be truncated.")
    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    .truncationMode(.middle)
```